# Error in dynamic allocation in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char *CopyOf(const char *str);

void main(void)
{
    char *hello = CopyOf("Hello\n");
    cout << hello;
    delete [] hello;
    system("pause");
}

char *CopyOf(const char *str)
{
    char *copy = new char(strlen(str) + 1);
    strcpy(copy, str);
    return copy;
}
```

My error occurs when the program runs into delete statement. Any suggestion?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You are allocating a single `char`.

Comment: `My error occurs when the program runs into delete statement`.  No, your error occurs at the call to `strcpy`.  This is a prime example of memory corruption occuring at a place in the code *before* the code crashes.

Comment: How do you know there is an error?  You really did ***not*** include that in your question.  Did you get a compiler error? a runtime crash?  Describe your results!

Comment: *RE: "my problem is solved edit"* the workflow is that you can accept an answer by a check mark on the answer you feel helped you most.  Why you would want to is another issue, with the not-so-warm welcome of downvotes.  But...pretend they don't exist, the points are fake, just absorb the information.  :-)

Comment: i can't upvote your answer because i don't have enough reputation. sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should allocate an array of `char`s, like so:

```
char *CopyOf(const char *str)
{
    char *copy = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
    strcpy(copy, str);
    return copy;
}
```

Note that I used brackets, not parentheses.  What you were doing with parentheses was initializing a *single* new `char` with the value `strlen(str) + 1`.  Then you overran the 1-byte buffer with the call to `strcpy`.  You should strongly consider using `std::string`; it will save you from a lot of this C heartache.

Also, to get your code to compile, you must add `#include <cstring>`.  Finally, `main()` should have return type of `int`.

Comment: Thank you. A lot of helpful information.

Answer (score 2):

Change this statement

```
char *copy = new char(strlen(str) + 1);
```

to

```
char *copy = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
```

Take into account that you have to include header `<cstring>` and `<cstdlib>` and that function main has to have return type `int`